# Opengl: Quadratic interplation between vertex and fragment shader

Tags: opengl

Is it possible to implement iterpolation that is of a higher order than linear when passing data from vertex to fragment shaders? Ideally I would like some form of quadratic interpolation, but that would require access to vertices beyond the corners of the face being interpolated across.

Answer (score 3):

*The short answer is: no.*

I do not think that there is a native support for interpolation other than linear if it comes to attributes passed from vertices to the fragment shader.

However you could incorporate a trick to have non linear interpolation by using geometry shader an inserting interpolated vertices in-between. Or, if you want so have some kind of distribution of values along the interpolated line, you can use a predefined 1D texture that will contain the interpolation curve you need to use in the fragment shader.

Comment: The geometry shader solution wouldn't really work, because for a smooth cubic or higher interpolation you need information about the neighbour faces.

Comment: Primitive Adjacency will help you here. @dari You can send this information to vertices by creating redundant attributes for each vertex with info about their neighborhood.